# Why is tab removed when cloning a Team?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a team (let's call it "Team A") configured with a new Tab in the General channel. When I create a new Team ("Team B") based on "Team A", it shows this Tab in the General tab but in an unconfigured state. So far so good.

When I go configure the Tab, it shows the configuration page and I click save. Now the Tab is completely removed from the General channel.
The Chrome Developer Console shows this error:

```
angular.min.js:112 TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
at Object.successFunc (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:874:4148)
at https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:5203
at c (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:258)
at o._resolveCallback (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:5182)
at https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:5074
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at o._resolveSuccesses (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:4992)
at o.resolve (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:3112)
at Object.successFunc (https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:5394)
at https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-7ba60abf.js:771:5203 Unhandled error caught in promise chain
```

How do I make the Tab show up?

Comment: Which Tab you had configured?

Comment: A custom developed Tab and the Website tab, both showing the same results.